# Derailed Benchmark Memory Over Time Fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, memory-leaks

I'm trying to debug my rails application with the `derailed_benchmarks` gem. I am following the instructions on their [Github](https://github.com/schneems/derailed_benchmarks). I can run my server locally in production, but when I try to execute the command `derailed exec perf:mem_over_time` I get the following error:

```
/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/derailed_benchmarks-1.1.3/lib/derailed_benchmarks/tasks.rb:92:in `call_app': Bad request: <html><body>You are being <a href="http://example.org/user_sessions/new">redirected</a>.</body></html> (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/derailed_benchmarks-1.1.3/lib/derailed_benchmarks/tasks.rb:145:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/derailed_benchmarks-1.1.3/bin/derailed:41:in `exec'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/derailed_benchmarks-1.1.3/bin/derailed:85:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/derailed:23:in `load'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/derailed:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/cowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My application uses puma, so I had to specify that when I ran the command.

```
$ USE_SERVER=puma derailed exec perf:mem_over_time
```